# extract text to NSString from html

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have an html string that I've received from UIWebView from this call:

```
NSString *html = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];
```

the content of the NSString is:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=508">
  <style type="text/css">
    img {max-width:100%;}
    div { margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}
    p{margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 0;word-wrap:break-word;}
    table{border-collapse: collapse;}
    td{word-wrap:break-word;font-family:Arial;vertical-align:top;}
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .bumpedFont16 { font-size:1.6em; }
    .bumpedFont20 { font-size:2.0em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:508;background-color:#FFFFFF; position:relative; overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word;min-height:830px; padding-left:20;padding-right:20;padding-top:20;padding-bottom:20;">
    <style type="text/css">
      .s0 {font-size: 12;font-family: Helvetica;color: rgb(0,0,0);}
      .s1 {direction:ltr;text-align: left;}
    </style>
    <p class="s1">
      <span class="s0">
        <span class="bumpedFont16">THIS IS A TEST</span>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I get the "THIS IS A TEST" from the html string into another NSString as a plain text without any formatting ?
Thank you!

Comment: Post the html as string not image :

Comment: I just did. not pretty, but the best I could do

Comment: is this your own html, could you remove the inline style, or that is not a good solution to u?

Comment: this is exactly as I get it from the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString I mention at the top.

Comment: Use document.documentElement.innerText, what do you get with that?

Comment: exactly what I need!!!!! thank you! please change this to an aswer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ok done :) also consider upvoting so users could find it more quickly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code instead of using

```
document.documentElement.innerHtml
```

Use

```
document.documentElement.innerText
```

Inner text will return (from chrome console)

```
document.documentElement.innerText  
"THIS IS A TEST"
```